# How to reduce the dimension of array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have an array items like this:

```
items = [[[["2012-09-01", 10], ["2011-09-10", 20]]], [[["2010-01-01", 23]]]]
```

How to reduce the 4 dimensional items to 2 dimensional array like this：

```
items = [["2012-09-01", 10], ["2011-09-10", 20], ["2010-01-01", 23]]
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Array#flatten. - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten

```
irb(main):001:0> items = [[[["2012-09-01", 10], ["2011-09-10", 20]]], [[["2010-01-01", 23]]]]
=> [[[["2012-09-01", 10], ["2011-09-10", 20]]], [[["2010-01-01", 23]]]]
irb(main):002:0> items.flatten(2)
=> [["2012-09-01", 10], ["2011-09-10", 20], ["2010-01-01", 23]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Ruby's flatten method.

You can specify the level amount to flatten.

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten